# outlook PST File extracting via libpst + python

Tags: python, email, parsing, outlook, pst

had anyone successfully import and used libpst via python, to extract outlook PST files : http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/ from source package?

It have python bindings but i cannot import after installing (even test.py script comes with it dont work)

Here is Mercurial repo to latest version. Can you guys give a try? i need help..

Comment: What error does the `test.py` give you?

Comment: ./test.py "/home/v3ss/workspace-bbb/web2py-clone/applications/sExtract/static/ediscov/demoCase/source/Group9-3_010104-123104_searchterms_T7_sentrec_DA.pst

returns nothing , but give a cross hair (wth??) and when i click something , it crashes 

./test.py: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./test.py: line 3: `ft = _libpst.FILETIME()'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually libpst Python is not well developed  , and i had to use from readpst commandline , wrapping inside subprocess call.

So i have to answer this my own.